# How to combine two sequences cumulatively in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have two sequences and I'd like to combine them so that any results coming into the second sequence would be cumulatively combined with the latest result from the first sequence.

```
A---------------B----------------------C------------- ...
-------1-2-----------3-------------------------------- ...
```

So that the result would be:

```
A-----A+1--A+1+2---B----B+3--------------C-------------
```

How might I do that in Rx? (I'm using RxSwift)

Comment: It is not clear from the question what do you mean by RESET event? Or does it even matter? If not you could use some abstract concept like Sequence A and Sequence B.

Answering your question, if I understood it correctly you can use `withLatestFrom`
https://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom

Comment: Sorry, edited my question -- hopefully it's more clear now

Comment: You need some kind of scan (accumulating the number) with the possibility to reset the accumulator when the letters emitted. Thats tricky. But try scan and play around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combineLatest` + `bufferWhen` 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-s1pemu

```
import {bufferWhen} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { timer, interval,combineLatest , } from 'rxjs';

// timerOne emits first value at 1s, then once every 4s
const timerOne$ = interval( 4000);
// timerTwo emits first value at 2s, then once every 4s
const timerTwo$ = interval(1000);
// timerThree emits first value at 3s, then once every 4s

// when one timer emits, emit the latest values from each timer as an array
combineLatest(
  timerOne$, 
  timerTwo$.pipe(bufferWhen(()=>timerOne$)), 
)
.subscribe(
  ([timerValOne, timerValTwo]) => {
    console.log(
    `Timer One Latest: ${timerValOne},
     Timer Two Latest: ${timerValTwo}`,
    );
    console.log('Total:', timerValOne+timerValTwo.reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr))
  }
);
```

Comment: I think that is not completely correct since it won't emit A+1 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Hopefully, you can use this as a template on how to write a test to establish what you want and then write the code that produces it.

```
enum Action<A, B> {
    case a(A)
    case b(B)
}

func example<A, B>(_ a: Observable<A>, _ b: Observable<B>) -> Observable<(A?, [B])> {
    return Observable.merge(a.map(Action.a), b.map(Action.b))
        .scan((A?.none, [B]())) { current, next in
            switch next {
                case .a(let a):
                    return (a, [])
                case .b(let b):
                    return (current.0, current.1 + [b])
            }
        }
}
```

And here is a test to prove it works:

```
class RxSandboxTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let a = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(0, "A"), .next(16, "B"), .next(39, "C")])
        let b = scheduler.createColdObservable([.next(7, 1), .next(9, 2), .next(21, 3)])

        let result = scheduler.start {
            example(a.asObservable(), b.asObservable())
                .map { Result(a: $0.0, b: $0.1) }
        }

        XCTAssertEqual(
            result.events,
            [
                .next(200, Result(a: "A", b: [])),
                .next(207, Result(a: "A", b: [1])),
                .next(209, Result(a: "A", b: [1, 2])),
                .next(216, Result(a: "B", b: [])),
                .next(221, Result(a: "B", b: [3])),
                .next(239, Result(a: "C", b: []))
            ]
        )
    }
}

struct Result: Equatable {
    let a: String?
    let b: [Int]
}
```